# Autohotkey Remap Wildcard Modifiers

Tags: autohotkey

How to remap Insert button to <kbd>PageDown</kbd>, without explicitly remapping modifier keys, such that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Insert</kbd> is taken as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>PgDn</kbd>,  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Insert</kbd> is taken as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>PgDn</kbd> etc.

I tried *, but it doesn't work:

```
*Insert:: Send {PgDn}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just after posting the question, I realized the answer was quite simple:

*Insert::PgDn